# Can't get georeferenced Autocad DXF to right coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson, autocad, dxf

I am not a frequent Autocad user.

I wanted to export some floorplans from Autocad 2016 DWG to a final GeoJSON file to be loaded in a Google maps JS app.

My steps are:

1)in Autocad set a location of one of the drawing points with Edit location-> From map, choosing an arbitrary SRS (Mercator, pseudo mercator, local)

2)save as DXF

3)open in QGIS setting the origin SRS, or convert with ogr2ogr setting source and dest SRS or load in https://mygeodata.cloud converter

4)view the shape: the shape is correct in both proportions and shape, but it always gets placed between Latin America and Africa ((0,0)???)

I don't know actually if i'm doing something wrong in Autocad or elsewhere but i have no more ideas left.

Comment: Welcome to the GIS SE! Can you tell if your CAD coordinates stored as World Coordinates or Object Coordinates?

Comment: Thanks BArbaross. I don't really know if it's the correct answer but in Autocad under the compass i have WCS and when i set the location from the map, i chose Pseudo Mercator for example. Activating the Bing maps layer underneath, the object gets correctly positioned (as long as we stay in autocad).

Comment: What i see is that if i move the cursor to draw a line, the coordinates are not in lat - lng even if i choose WORLD-MERCATOR as SRS, could it be related to a WCS/UCS problem? Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?